# I can't open files using command via WSL

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using windows 10 and I've installed ubuntu 18.04 via wsl. Now I created a blank html file. I can't open the file using default application (chrome in my case) within the directory using ubuntu terminal? I've tried commands like `open`, `xdg-open`, `start`, etc. But no results. I'm attaching the screenshot of the errors. Please suggest the proper command.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to use Ubuntu as a replacement for powershell.
Instead, you need to think of it as a separate operating system. The reason you can't open a file in chrome, is that you don't have chrome installed in Ubuntu. 
Opening any program with a graphical interface is not easy, and will require a lot of set up.
There are some command line browsers which you can search for, or if you just want to view the file, you can use `cat index.html` which will print the contents to the screen.